# C# Code explanation

Tags: c#, boolean, code-snippets

i've this piece of code from an open source c# program.

I'm trying to figure out the purpose behind this snippet.

```
internal static bool ReadAsDirectoryEntry(BinaryReader br)
    {
        bool dir;

        br.BaseStream.Seek(8, SeekOrigin.Current);
        dir = br.ReadInt32() < 0;
        br.BaseStream.Seek(-12, SeekOrigin.Current);

        return dir;
    }
```

The code on LINE 6 is unclear to me , can anyone explain what it does ?
How can a bool have a value of the returned int32 and smaller than zero ?

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readint32.aspx

Comment: I've should have added that i know what br.ReadInt32() does :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
internal static bool ReadAsDirectoryEntry(BinaryReader br)
{
    bool dir;

    // Skip 8 bytes starting from current position
    br.BaseStream.Seek(8, SeekOrigin.Current);

    // Read next bytes as an Int32 which requires 32 bits (4 bytes) to be read 
    // Store whether or not this integer value is less then zero
    // Possibly it is a flag which holds some information like if it is a directory entry or not
    dir = br.ReadInt32() < 0;

    // Till here, we read 12 bytes from stream. 8 for skipping + 4 for Int32
    // So reset stream position to where it was before this method has called
    br.BaseStream.Seek(-12, SeekOrigin.Current);

    return dir;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You read an int and check if this int is smaller than 0. The expression `br.ReadInt32() < 0` will result in a bool. This bool result you assign to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

basically, that is *logically equivalent to* (but terser than):

```
bool dir;
int tmp = br.ReadInt32();
if(tmp < 0)
{
    dir = true;
}
else
{
    dir = false;
}
```

It:

- does the call to `ReadInt32()` (which will result in an `int`)
- tests whether the result of that is `< 0` (which will result in either `true` or `false`)
- and assigns that result (`true` or `false`) to `dir`

To basically, it will return `true` *if and only if* the call to `ReadInt32()` gives a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

The line 6 means : read an Int32 then compare it to 0 and then store the comparison result into a Boolean.

It's equivalent as :

```
Int32 tmp = br.ReadInt32();
dir =  tmp < 0;
```